# EventListener on MovieClip including TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, event-listener

I'm trying to create a cutom made clickablle field using AS3 but I have problem registering an OnClickListener.

What I do is create a subclass of MovieClip, draw a RoundRect on it and add a textfield as a child. Now when I click on that "thing", events are caught by the textField and I can't find a way to forward it to my MovieClip.

```
private function addListChild(i:Number, l:Number, c:Content):void {
    var x:Number = 100;
    var y:Number = 100; 
    var width:Number = 200:
    var height:Number = 20;         

    var menuitemMV:ContentMV = new ContentMV(c);

    //set background        
    menuitemMV.graphics.beginFill(MyGestureManager.midgrey, 1.0);
    menuitemMV.graphics.drawRoundRect(x5, y5, width5, height5, 8,8);
    menuitemMV.graphics.endFill();

    //Create text label 
    var listText:TextField = new TextField();
    listText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    listText.selectable = false;
    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.color = MyGestureManager.lightGrey;
    format.size = iconHeight * 0.4
    listText.defaultTextFormat = format;
    listText.appendText(c.getName());
    listText.x = x+5;
    listText.y = y;

    menuitemMV.addChild(listText);
    addChild(menuitemMV);

    menuitemMV.addEventListener(TuioTouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN, handleDown); 
    listText.addEventListener(TuioTouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN, handleDown); 
}
```

How can I now forward the ClickEvent registered by the textfield forward to my button to work with it...?
Any idea, or is it even clear what I mean?

Comment: It isn't really clear.. Please try to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
menuitemMV.mouseChildren = false;
```

on the "thing". every click on a submc should trigger the click-eventlistener of the parent now.